# Compress a Sentence

Tags: python, python-3.4, compression

i'm working on a compress and decompress code of the user's sentence.
I have made this code:

```
import gzip
sentence = input(b"Please enter a sentence ")
varNameIn = (b"sentence")
varNameOut = gzip.compress(varNameIn)
print(varNameOut)
varNameDecon = gzip.decompress(varNameOut)
print(varNameDecon)
```

But something seems wrong. It works with the out put of:

b'Please enter a sentence 'gn h 
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00Z\xedxX\x02\xff+N\xcd+I\xcdKN\x05\x00\xd5Nf\x9d\x08\x00\x00\x00'
b'sentence'

Why does it show b'sentence' instead of the user's sentence and when it's asking for a sentence why does it have b'  ' instead of Please enter...
I got told the b'   ' will make the sentence compress in the future step of the code.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Er, because you defined `varNameIn` as `b"sentence"`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: my  guess: that's an attempt to turn the `sentence` value into a `bytes` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`b"sentence"` does not turn `sentence` into a `bytes` value. You need to [**encode** a string to bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) instead. Pick a codec that suits your use case; here encoding to UTF-8 probably is best as it can encode all of Unicode, with a reasonable small size for western text:

```
sentence = input("Please enter a sentence ")
varNameIn = sentence.encode('utf8')
varNameOut = gzip.compress(varNameIn)
```

Note that `input()` always returns a `str` type, giving it a `bytes` prompt won't change that.

Note that when you decompress the data again, you'll still have a `bytes` object. If you want to turn that back into a `str` object, [*decode* from `bytes` to `str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) using the same encoding:

```
varNameDecon = gzip.decompress(varNameOut)
print(varNameDecon.decode('utf-8'))
```